# JDBC Connector Confluent Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Можно ли в конфигурации JDBC sink Connector Kafka каким-нибудь образом вызвать процедуру?
Ознакомился с https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html
Там нет подходящих опций, но они явно не все там указаны, так как я в конфиге использую transformation, которого нет в документации.
Есть ли общие опции для всех коннекторов?

Comment: Здесь перечислены конфигурации для воркеров: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html
Но там нет инфы о том, как вызвать процедуру. Вот тут https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/590 пишут о том, что в принципе можно самому кастомизировать коннектор и вызывать процедуру своими руками. Я пробовал писать кастомные коннекторы и могу сказать, что это действительно не особо тяжело.
P.S. Не уверен, что это тянет на ответ, но если поможет - отпишись, запосчу как ответ.

Comment: Да, можно считать за ответ. Кастомизация коннектора подходит. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь перечислены конфигурации для воркеров: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html
Но там нет инфы о том, как вызвать процедуру. Вот тут https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/590 пишут о том, что в принципе можно самому кастомизировать коннектор и вызывать процедуру своими руками. Я пробовал писать кастомные коннекторы и могу сказать, что это действительно не особо тяжело.